# Android App - Is it possible to connect to different Stripes sellers accounts?

Tags: android, android-studio, stripe-payments, stripes

I really appreciate any tip on this. I am new to Android/Stripe.

I want my app to be able to collect payments for different vendors. I offers a ticketing solution for events and I would like when a customer pay for an event, it pays to the organiser's Stripe account. I thought something like connecting to Stripe with the organiser's public key when the customer pays but I only see examples of stripes-android integration with an unique Stripe account.

+1 On the same topic, is it possible to skip the server and solve everything on the app/client side? or the server is a must to perform Stripes payments.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you think it's a good idea paying to organisers directly? This means they have to set up a Stripe account too. It makes more sense for the users to pay to your business, then you disburse the proceeds to the organisers (less any applicable fees on your business level).

Edit: If you wish to integrate everything with Stripe, look at Connect: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide

No, there is no way to process Stripe payments client-sided.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want them to pay directly to avoid me trouble, not sure if I want to handle all the money, not sure how it works in terms of taxes.. I am new on payment systems and I would like to be involve as little as possible.

Comment: actually your link is helpful.. want sure Stripes could handle everything without involving banks. Thanks.

Comment: Yup, I had a read on Connect and it seems to support your use case. Pls accept my answer if it helped!